# Moonlight raked the lawn

Tags: ambiguity, metaphors

Years ago, I saw a discussion about a writer who had, allegedly without humorous intent, injected some surprising atmosphere into a story by saying that "moonlight raked the lawn".

The contributors to the discussion all recognised the silliness of the metaphor, and vigorously tried to analyse the nature of this gaffe — without, it must be said, achieving any great insight.

In the process, what became clear is that few people could invent other metaphors that produced the same type of comic effect. I find myself still interested whether there's a concise name for a metaphor with this type of failing. More interesting for me, how can a linguistic trick whose humour is so intuitively understood have so few ready examples?

Comment: I don't get it, what's so funny about "moonlight raked the lawn"?

Comment: The author meant it figuratively, suggesting that the light skimmed over the surface of the lawn. But it conjures images of a nocturnal and celestial leaf-clearing  phenomenon, because "rake" and "lawn" routinely go together in a literal sense.

Comment: Perhaps I've read too much poetry, but I really only see the author's intended imagery. I'm quite sure the author fully realized and understood the "raked the lawn" connection.

Comment: Why they named their daughter *Moonlight* we'll never know.

Comment: "Moonlight raked the lawn" is amusing in the same way "Moonlight washed the car" is: As a metaphorical action, it is vivid and somewhat striking; but this positive quality is significantly undermined by the susceptibility of the phrase to a mundane and literalist reading that renders the artiness of the intended image somehow absurd. I am not aware of any specific term for this particular combination of intended and unintended meanings.

Comment: I don't think the expression is funny, for me it is cumbersome. Moonlight and the activity of raking a lawn don't fit together. The expression looks like someone who wants to coin a new variant without a feeling for language and images. What would you think about "Moonlight ploughed the garden" or  "Moonlight whitewashed the wall""? Childish images.

Comment: @rogermue Actually, I quite like "Moonlight whitewashed the wall." I do wonder how bright a moon you'd need for that to happen, though.

Comment: I see the moon in  white  overalls  and a  pail of paint working on the wall with a brush.

Comment: @user867: If the moon were really bright, he'd work out a way to get his friends to whitewash the wall for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lost violin found by tree.
>
> Bridge held up by red tape.

The old fashioned name for this is **Amphibole**.  There is renewed interest in the form due to the work being done on machine translation. Amongst this brotherhood it is known as **global semantic ambiguity** if both meanings make some sort of sense.

> General MacArthur flies back to front.

is a similar figure (also an Amphibole) known as **Global Syntactic Ambiguity**.

Fowler and pre-1980 dictionaries call this Amphibole: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amphibology) now calls it **Amphiboly**,or **Amphibology**.

> Definition of AMPHIBOLOGY :  a sentence or phrase (as “nothing is good
>   enough for you”) that can be interpreted in more than one way

[Oxford on line](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/amphibology) also now calls it **Amphibology**

For more informatio see  http://au.wow.com/wiki/Amphiboly and for more entertainment  see site:::  http://www.nytimes.com/2010/01/31/magazine/31FOB-onlanguage-t.html?_r=0

Comment: The only definition I find for "amphibole" is: "Any of a group of rock-forming ferromagnesian silicates." Any chance you can add a link to your answer for support? :)

Comment: @medica, sorry about that.  It is an indication of the speed at which the terminology in linguistics is changing.  Amphibole to rhyme with 'bowl' is the Elizabethan word that remained in use until  **...**

Comment: @Hugh, thanks for that answer which I think gives a good explanation of the mechanism and for the name, and especially for letting me know about the current research. My wife is a translator and she'll find this interesting (and amusing) too.